# How do I convert these drupal 6 tags into php variables?

Tags: php, variables, drupal

I'm looking for a way to take apart the $content variable, and utilize its contents. Below is a sample of the code I got when using the `print_r($node)` command to see how Drupal was creating the `$content` variable. How should I arrange the description so that I can just output this as a variable, without the image? Thanks everyone graciously for your help!

```
 [content] => Array
        (
            [#content_extra_fields] => Array
                (
                    [subscriptions_ui] => Array
                        (
                            [label] => Subscribe
                            [description] => Subscriptions UI module form.
                            [weight] => 100
                        )

                    [title] => Array
                        (
                            [label] => Title
                            [description] => Node module form.
                            [weight] => -5
                        )

                    [body_field] => Array
                        (
                            [label] => Body
                            [description] => Node module form.
                            [weight] => 0
                            [view] => body
                        )

                    [revision_information] => Array
                        (
                            [label] => Revision information
                            [description] => Node module form.
                            [weight] => 20
                        )

                    [author] => Array
                        (
                            [label] => Authoring information
                            [description] => Node module form.
                            [weight] => 20
                        )

                    [options] => Array
                        (
                            [label] => Publishing options
                            [description] => Node module form.
                            [weight] => 25
                        )

                    [comment_settings] => Array
                        (
                            [label] => Comment settings
                            [description] => Comment module form.
                            [weight] => 30
                        )

                    [menu] => Array
                        (
                            [label] => Menu settings
                            [description] => Menu module form.
                            [weight] => -2
                        )

                    [path] => Array
                        (
                            [label] => Path settings
                            [description] => Path module form.
                            [weight] => 30
                        )

                    [attachments] => Array
                        (
                            [label] => File attachments
                            [description] => Upload module form.
                            [weight] => 30
                            [view] => files
                        )

                    [path_redirect] => Array
                        (
                            [label] => URL redirects
                            [description] => Path redirect module listing
                            [weight] => 30
                        )

                )

            [#pre_render] => Array
                (
                    [0] => content_alter_extra_weights
                )

            [body] => Array
                (
                    [#weight] => 0
                    [#value] =>
```

Comment: use unset to unset respective elements!

Comment: I'm sorry... could you give example using some of the [labels] above? Thank you VERY much for your help!